# Interface for a slice of arbitrary structs to use as a function parameter (golang)

Tags: go, struct, reflection, interface, slice

I have two different types of structs in my app.

*I'll show it as a simplified example:*

```
type typeA struct {
    fieldA1 int
    fieldA2 string
}

type typeB struct {
    fieldB1 float32
    fieldB2 bool
}
```

First I init slices of them, then I want to store them in DB.

```
a := []typeA{
    {10, "foo"},
    {20, "boo"},
}
b := []typeB{
    {2.5, true},
    {3.5, false},
}
```

My first attempt was to iterate over first slice, then over second slice. It works just fine, but doesn't look [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). The code is clearly duplicated:

```
printBothArrays(a, b)

// ...

func printBothArrays(dataA []typeA, dataB []typeB) {
    // Not DRY
    for i, row := range dataA {
        fmt.Printf("printBothArrays A row %d: %v\n", i, row)
    }
    for i, row := range dataB {
        fmt.Printf("printBothArrays B row %d: %v\n", i, row)
    }
}
```

A wrong way to make it DRY is to split it into 2 functions:

```
printArrayA(a)
printArrayB(b)

// ...

func printArrayA(data []typeA) {
    // Not DRY too, because the code is just split between 2 funcs
    for i, row := range data {
        fmt.Printf("printArrayA row %d: %v\n", i, row)
    }
}

func printArrayB(data []typeB) {
    // Not DRY too, because the code is just split between 2 funcs
    for i, row := range data {
        fmt.Printf("printArrayB row %d: %v\n", i, row)
    }
}
```

These two functions' signatures are different, but the code is just the same!

I thought of an universal function which can take any []struct and just store it. As my store function can take any interface{}, I thought of this:

```
func printArrayAny(data [](interface{})) {
    for i, row := range data {
        fmt.Printf("printArrayAny row %d: %v\n", i, row)
    }
}
```

But I've tried different ways and I can't match any shared interface. I'm getting errors like:

`cannot use a (type []typeA) as type []interface {} in argument to printArrayAny`

I don't really want to make any heavy lifting like converting it to `[]map[string]interface`, or using `reflect`, as both slices are really big.

Is there a way to modify `printArrayAny` so it can receive and iterate over any arbitrary `[]struct` ?

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/qHzcQNUtLIX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/refelect) package to iterate over arbitrary slice types:

```
func printArrayAny(data interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("printArrayAny row %d: %v\n", i, v.Index(i).Interface())
    }
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/6JmgE-vEpBC).